# opacity: 0; implemented before transition-delay: 100s;

Tags: css, css-transitions, opacity

To reproduce issue, just click on the screen.

Mouse click on the black screen.

After I click on the black screen, the black becomes transparent.

Why is this happening, what is causing it to occur, and how is that fixed in the code?

Does anyone know what seems to be the issue here?

I can't seem to figure it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/1knja4rd/

Why is `opacity: 0;` being implemented before `transition-delay: 100s;`?

If you look at the screen up close, you can see the background in it.

It's visible in the snippet also, full page view.

Why is this occurring?

It doesn't make sense for opacity to be implemented before transition-delay.

[image]

```js
(function (d) {
  const tv = d.querySelector(".curtain");
  tv.addEventListener("click", screenOff);
  function screenOff() {
   tv.classList.remove("off");
setTimeout(() => tv.classList.add("off"), 10);
  }

})(document);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  --color-a: blue;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: red;
  --color-d: black;

  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b)70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-content: center;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.curtain {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 642px;
  /*box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0px 0px #0a0a0a;*/
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  /* background: #0a0a0a;*/

}

.ratio-keeper:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0a0a0a;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.off .ratio-keeper::before {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: 100s;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="curtain ">

    <div class="ratio-keeper">


      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="inner">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would a `@keyframes` solution be sufficient rather than JS?

Comment: css Transition is being used in the code. Anyone can provide any answer that fixes this issue. Would you be able to know why opacity: 0; is being implemented before transition-delay: 100s;? Do you know why that is? Is there a reason for that? Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: I would like to know what the issue seems to be with the transition code.